# Перевод выражения в код ассемблера

Tags: c++, c

Есть программа который переводит выражение в обратную польскую запись и потом вычисляет результат. мне нужно в момент вычисления транслировать выражение в код ассемблера в output.txt файле. Например:

```
  5 - 10 + 20 * 5 - 30 + 3
```

> assign R0, 20
>
> assign R4, 5
>
> mul R0, R4, R0
>
> assign R4, 5
>
> assign R8, 10
>
> sub R4, R8, R4
>
> add R4, R0, R0
>
> assign R4, 30
>
> sub R0, R4, R0
>
> assing R4, 3
>
> add R0, R4, R0

Как реализовать такую задачу, чтобы программа правильно распределял выражение по регистрам а потом записывал?

Comment: Вы действительно хотите написать фортран еще раз?

Comment: не у меня домашняя работа нужно просто генерировать код ассемблера из выражения

Comment: Если нужно генерить для ARM, может поможет этот [набор макросов](https://github.com/kisssko/armin/blob/master/armin.h).

Comment: Стек можно использовать? Количество регистров ограничено?

Comment: да можно использовать stl и регистры 4

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку - берете список регистров вашего процессора
Берете переменную. Фильтруете список, отбрасывая те регистры, которые

- уже заняты
- в которые эту переменную положить нельзя,
- те регистры с которыми нельзя выполнить требуемую операцию

Если остался непустой список, размещаете переменную в первый из регистров.

Если получился пустой список - возвращаемся в начало и пробуем укладывать переменные в другом порядке.

Comment: У него же нет переменных...

Comment: если не сложно можете написать пример кода в c++ 
     generateCode(leftOperand, rightOperand, operation); в этой функции нужно правильно распределить операнды по регистрам .. нужен код который проверяет в какой регистр передать операнды и сделать операцию